# HP ENVY replacement battery drains fast

Tags: battery, hp-envy

I paid to get my battery replaced on my 2018 HP ENVY since the original one was starting to swell and lift my case up. The repair guy has the replacement battery details so I don’t know what he replaced it with.

But he said it’s new from his computer parts supplier. When I took the laptop home the battery was at 83% I noticed it was draining fast, almost losing a percent every two minutes.

At 50%, I shut it down (unplugged) and restarted it some hours later. I got a CMOS corrupt code error and something about updating bios. So now I have it plugged in and shutdown to give it a full charge overnight.

I assumed a new battery would come fully charge and also I expected the charge to last atleast 4-6 hours. Is this a wrong assumption? How can I check if the battery is indeed a new one? Thanks!

Comment: A battery does not necessarily come fully charged. You should probably go back to the repair guy and get your money back.

Comment: Agree with Gantendo. You can also try the following;  Allow to fully discharge (not below 8 to 10%). Shut down the computer, plug in the adapter and charge to 100%. This may exercise the battery and make it work correctly. If not return it.

Comment: Most "repair guys" will pull the trigger on a cheap knockoff battery.  Original OEM batteries cut from their bottom line.  I myself have had luck with some knockoffs and not so much (like you) with others.

Comment: Actually such batteries should be stored at around 60% charge, and the system should detect it correctly (not as 100%).